# [jest]: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

While writing jest tests, I needed to use [memfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs) as a mock for the Nodejs native file system module, so I used jest's [manual mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks), but I'm getting this error:

```
> rimraf tests/{coverage,public} && jest

 PASS  tests/x.test.ts (19.926 s)
 FAIL  tests/mix.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
        at Function.setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)

      at node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:139:39
      at patch (node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:141:5)
      at patch (node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:104:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:96:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:5:12)

 PASS  tests/options.test.ts (35.412 s)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Tests:       6 passed, 6 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        36.834 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Here are the files for a minimal reproduction of the error:

```js
// src/index.ts
// this is just a minimal reproduction
import "laravel-mix";
import fs from "fs";

export default function getContent(path: string) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path, "utf-8");
}
```

```js
// tests/index.test.ts

import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import memfs from "memfs";
import getContent from "../src";

// Use memfs instead of native fs module.
jest.mock("fs");
jest.mock("fs/promises");

beforeAll(() => {
  memfs.fs.mkdirSync(path.resolve(), {recursive: true});
});

// this is for demonstration only.
test("should mock fs", () => {
    expect(fs).toBe(memfs.fs);
});

test("returns content from memfs", () => {
    memfs.fs.writeFileSync("test.txt", "test text");

    const result = getContent("test.txt");

    expect(result).toBe("test text");
});

// more tests
```

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    collectCoverageFrom: ["src/*.ts"],
    coverageDirectory: "tests/coverage",
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "node",
    testMatch: ["<rootDir>/tests/**/*.test.ts"],
};
```

```json
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "importHelpers": true
  }
}
```

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "jest-mock-error-reproduction",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.8",
    "@types/serve-static": "^1.13.10",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.29",
    "memfs": "^3.2.4",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "typescript": "~4.2.0"
  }
}
```

And the manual mock files:

```js
// __mocks__/fs.ts

import {fs} from "memfs";

export default fs;
```

```js
// __mocks__/fs/promises.ts

import {fs} from "memfs";

export default fs.promises;
```

Note that when I remove :

```
jest.mock("fs");
jest.mock("fs/promises");
```

from `tests/index.test.ts`, tests fail as expected.

I tried debugging the source code that produces the error, and I couldn't find the problem.

I also tried to use `import * as memfs from "memfs"` syntax in the `__mock__` files, because from other answers it seems like that solves the problem, but the error persists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"Here's a reproduction of it."_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not only a link to an external resource that might not be available for whatever reason, or change, or ...

Comment: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to narrow the source of the problem down to a dependency.

It seems like [memfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs) is not compatible with [graceful-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs) which is a dependency of [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) which in turn is a dependency of a library I'm using in my own code ([laravel-mix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix)). So here's a very minimal reproduction of the error now:

```js
// tests/index.test.ts

import fs from "fs";
import memfs from "memfs";
import "graceful-fs"; // comment this and the test should pass.

jest.mock("fs");
jest.mock("fs/promises");

test("should mock fs", () => {
    expect(fs).toBe(memfs.fs);
});
```

To solve my issue, I changed the virtual file system library in use. I switched from [memfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs) to [mock-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs).

First, I installed `mock-fs` and `@types/mock-fs`:

```
npm i -D mock-fs @types/mock-fs
```

And then I used it in `tests/index.test.ts`:

```js
// tests/index.test.ts

import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import mock_fs from "mock-fs";
import getContent from "../src";

beforeEach(() => {
    mock_fs();
});

afterEach(() => {
    mock_fs.restore();
});

test("returns content from mocked fs", () => {
    fs.writeFileSync("test.txt", "test text");

    const result = getContent("test.txt");

    expect(result).toBe("test text");
});

// more tests
```